# What does it mean that "Flows in RxJava are sequential in nature..."

Tags: rx-java, rx-java2

I'm reading the docs for RxJava and came across this which I don't really understand. https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava

> Flows in RxJava are sequential in nature split into processing stages
>   that may run concurrently with each other:
>
> ```
> Flowable.range(1, 10)
>   .observeOn(Schedulers.computation())
>   .map(v -> v * v)
>   .blockingSubscribe(System.out::println);
> ```

Nothing about that block of code seems like it would run concurrently to me.

Comment: Did you keep reading? The next paragraph explains how you could parallelise.

Comment: `System.out::println` runs on the main thread concurrently with the computation `v * v`. Another name for this is pipelining.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I did keep reading, but my question boils down to my last sentence. The quoted section does not seem like it would run concurrently (to me at least)... yet it states "that may run concurrently with each other:"

Comment: @akarnokd are you saying that there's a chance that this could print out of order?

Comment: No. It prints in order. The concurrency refers to the computation stages being concurrent: practically each operator applied can be considered a stage. For example, while 5 * 5 is executing on the computation thread, the main thread prints 4 from the earlier computation.

Comment: @akarnokd aha. That makes sense. So .map() is a stage and .blockingSubscribe() is a stage, and they'll run concurrently if they are altered by a scheduler as in the above example?

Answer (score 0):

Squares the numbers from 1 to 10 on the computation (Worker) thread, and and consumes the results on the "main" thread. The lambda `v -> v * v` doesn't run in parallel, while v+1 * v+1 (range 1-10) is  executing on the computation thread `System.out::println` run for earlier v*v on main thread.

Comment: How does it consume on the main thread? Wouldn't it also be on the computation thread?